# jQuery Mobile mailto - cancel email stays in mail app

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a web app with a mail option in jQuery Mobile.
The web app is added to my homescreen.
When you press the mail button my iPhone opens a new email with the email address filled in but when I press cancel and delete draft it stays in the mail app.

Can I force it to go back to the web app ?
This only occurs when using the web app from homescreen. In safari it works fine.

```
<a href="mailto:email@example.be"  data-role="button" data-inline="true" 
   data-theme="d" rel="external" data-mini="true">Mail</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not. Since you are developing a webapp, the only way to send an email is to open the mail app.

After the mail app is started it will display a new mail composer. Which if you user cancel you will go back to the mail client.