# Email app close event on a mobile device

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a mobile website built with jQueryMobile. Inside that site I have a page with an Email link. When user click the email link, an email client is opened (which is installed on the mobile device) and user can then send email. Pretty straightforward.

But now, after the emailing is done, is there any way to detect that the email client is closed or finished its task? So that after it return to the original page I can do some work.

Is there any JavaScript event? or anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ideally this should not be possible, as there can be several email clients on a mobile device and user could choose any, so how will JavaScript be aware of the chosen email client and capture its close event, security wise also i do not thing we would have any access to the  email clients from JavaScript (in purely mobile website, in phone gap we may build a plugin for that), same applies to a link that has a telephone number href:"tel:12345677", this will only aid opening of the phone call app, but user needs to manually close this to go back to the original website.

Duplicate of :

[jQuery Mobile mailto - cancel email stays in mail app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841067/jquery-mobile-mailto-cancel-email-stays-in-mail-app)